# What is the meaning of "with all the implication for the earth" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "with all the implication for the earth" in the following sentence,

> In addition to energy consumption, producing billions of new 5G
> devices and replacing all previous generation devices will lead to a
> huge demand for rare metals such as lithium, which must be mined,
> ***with all the implications for the earth***.

?  (Source: https://www.jrseco.com/how-much-power-does-5g-consume/ )

Does "with all the implication for the earth" mean "In addition to lithium, all other minerals on Earth must be mined" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"With all the implications [that that will have] for the Earth."

The sense is that a great increase in mining for rare metals such as lithium will have considerable implications for the Earth (that is, it will cause a lot of harm to the environment).